# Wrk HTTP benchmarking tool adding multiple parameters

Tags: url, parameters, wrk

I'm using the wrk tool for testing and having trouble adding additional parameters to the url.  Right now I have it as:

```
wrk -d10s -t20 -c20 http://localhost:7040/api/features/FeatureA?accountId=2233&applicationName=App1
```

but when I execute it I get [wrk command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHiII.jpg)

it gives a number in a bracket followed by more numbers:

[1] 121

then executes the command but cuts off the second parameter. 
After completion it returns the stats as it usually does but has another line:

[1] + Done

followed by the command as far as the first parameter ends.

Any help please, am I inputting the parameters wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You need to quote URL. Like

`wrk -d10s -t20 -c20 "http://localhost:7040/api/features/FeatureA?accountId=2233&applicationName=App1"`

Answer (score 0):

Got it, ended up using a lua script to add parameters